# help with filling up form: Petition for Extension of Time 37 CFR 1.136(a)

Tags: forms, extension, filling, 1.136a

A simple one, but slightly confused: in the [form](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0022.pdf), the 3rd row titled: "For": I am assuming this is supposed to be the title of the invention, and NOT the purpose of filing the petition. Please correct me if I'm wrong!
Thanks!!!
ps: where can I find sample already filled USPTO forms (without having to go on an exploration of PAIR)

Answer (score 1):

I "petitioned" for extensions of time many many times in my practice as a patent agent and never filled out this form. A transmittal letter (with the substantive submittal  that is coming in late) that says you are paying for the time extension + actual payment is all that is needed. I put petitioned in quotes because this is barely a petition. It is automatically granted and does not go through the bureaucratic channels for petitions.

It is important to know that you ask for the time extension when you send in whatever was late AND send in the payment.

In a more direct answer to the question - it isn't very clear what is expected in that location on the form. I'd put the title of the invention.

Comment: Thanks for the response, George! Will remember to put in the transmittal letter as suggested.